# Is there a app or python package for managing background python script add,execute,stop?

Tags: python, process, background, at-job

I want an app or python package that can

1.Dynamically add python script to the background

2.Execute a specified time

3.Check is this python script is running,

4.Also i can kill the current execute script.

Is already has such package,so i needn't care about cron, at, check processing is running etc.

Cron only can provide execute job periodically,AT provide execute job once at future.
They didn't supply well wrapped python package, although there's a python-crontab, but it wasn't work

What I want is a process control management, like start,monitor process current status, I found the **supervisor** is exactly what I want, also it provide a web gui & xmlprc for intergate it into my app.

I think supervisor is a better choice,and it's provide a high level API, I hope i have explain why I don't use Cron & AT clearly

Comment: "any advice is appreciated".  Advice #1.  Please use Capital Letters for Proper Nouns and the Beginning of Sentences.  Advice #2.  Please format your question so that we can read it.  Advice #3.  Please specify **in detail** what's wrong with `cron`, since it does everything you need.

Comment: Please use Capital Letters for Proper Nouns and the Beginning of Sentences. Please.  Please specify in detail what's wrong with cron, since it does everything you need.  Please.

Comment: @S.Lott cron only can provide execute job periodly,what i want is a process control management,like start,monitor,i found the supervisor is what exactly what i want,also it provide a web gui & xmlprc for intergate it in my app

Comment: @S.Lott sorry for my poor english

Comment: @mizboy: Don't apologize.  Please **update** your question to use capital letters and explain why cron and at are unsuitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at http://supervisord.org/.